# Why is the variance formula different to the portfolio variance formula?

Tags: statistics, finance, economics

I'm trying to wrap my head around the variance, covariance and correlation. I'm clear on the formulas in their basic forms. However, confused as to why the portfolio variance formula is:$$Std^2=(W_a^2)(Std_a^2)+(W_b^2)(Std_b^2)+(2)(W_a)(W_b)(Cov_{a,b}).$$Whereas Variance in stats is:$$Std^2=\sum \frac{(x-mean)^2}{n}.$$Is this because it measures two variances?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Sample variance versus population variance.

Comment: And additionally in the first case you have the variance of weighted sum of two random variables (a,b) like $var(w*a+(1-w)*b)$ In the second case there is only one variable x: $var(x)$ The two formulas  are not comparable in many ways.